# Check latency if server denies ping requests

Tags: ping, latency

the server I need to check the latency of is denying PING requests, is there another way to check my latency to the server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of server is it ?

Comment: A game server, on port 7171

Comment: Is there any sort of "dummy" message it needs to respond to ?

Comment: I don't know, what you mean.

Comment: Well, the server needs to answer to some sort of message in order to measure latency. Is there any such message ?

Comment: I doubt that, just thru the game-client I guess, then it has to respond to many actions

Answer (score 8):

Use a ping based on TCP.

If you have access to a Windows box, use http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx

Download the zip, unpack. From CMD prompt cd to unpacked folder, then run with -t flag like this:

```
psping.exe -t www.anywebsite.com:80
```

[image: psping to remote host with open TCP port]

Please note: this assumes you have a web site running on remote host (port 80 in example above)

Answer (score 2):

Some people recommend [hping](http://www.hping.org/) which can use other protocols like TCP (for when ICMP is denied).

Note that I haven't tried it so I would be curious to know your experience if you do.